# Combining two JOIN queries together

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I have 3 tables Appliance, Tx_property, Rx_property

```
#Appliance Table structure:
  -id
  -tx_property_id
  -rx_property_id
  -...

#Tx_property Table structure:
  -id
  -...

#Rx_property Table structure:
  -id
  -...
```

Constraint are set on rx_property.id = appliance.id and tx_property.id = appliance.id

Is it possible to run only one query to retrieve all records from Appliance table that have corresponding entries in (based on rx_property_id and tx_property_id) ?

In summary, I'd like to combine 2 queries below into one.

```
select * from appliance INNER JOIN rx_property ON rx_property.id= appliance.rx_property_id;
select * from appliance INNER JOIN tx_property.id ON tx_property.id= appliance.tx_property_id;
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Edit:

So if I have sample records such as below:

```
appliance records:
id = 70
tx_property_id = 11
rx_property_id = null

id = 71
tx_property_id = 12
rx_property_id = null

id = 72
tx_property_id = null
rx_property_id = 11

id = 73
tx_property_id = null
rx_property_id = 12

tx_property records:
id = 11
name = 'tx_aa'

id = 12
name = 'tx_bb'

rx_property records:
id = 11
name = 'rx_aa'

id = 12
name = 'rx_bb'
```

I want 4 of them to be retrieved as:

```
appliance.id = 70
appliance.tx_property_id = 11
appliance.rx_property_id = null
tx_property.id = 11
tx_property.name = 'tx_aa'

appliance.id = 71
appliance.tx_property_id = 12
appliance.rx_property_id = null
tx_property.id = 12
tx_property.name = 'tx_bb'

appliance.id = 72
appliance.tx_property_id = null
appliance.rx_property_id = 11
tx_property.id = 11
tx_property.name = 'rx_aa'

appliance.id = 73
appliance.tx_property_id = null
appliance.rx_property_id = 12
tx_property.id = 11
tx_property.name = 'rx_aa'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can join both tables to `appliance` in a single query:

```
select * 
from appliance a
join rx_property r on r.id = a.rx_property_id
join tx_property t on t.id = a.tx_property_id
```

The above query returns only these rows which are referencing to both tables. If you want to get all rows, use `left join`:

```
select * 
from appliance a
left join rx_property r on r.id = a.rx_property_id
left join tx_property t on t.id = a.tx_property_id;

 id | rx_property_id | tx_property_id | id | name  | id | name  
----+----------------+----------------+----+-------+----+-------
 70 |             11 |                | 11 | rx_aa |    | 
 71 |             12 |                | 12 | rx_bb |    | 
 72 |                |             11 |    |       | 11 | tx_aa
 73 |                |             12 |    |       | 12 | tx_bb
(4 rows)
```

You can use `coalesce()` in the select list to chose not null column, example:

```
select 
    a.id, rx_property_id, tx_property_id,
    coalesce(r.name, t.name) as property_name
from appliance a
left join rx_property r on r.id = a.rx_property_id
left join tx_property t on t.id = a.tx_property_id

 id | rx_property_id | tx_property_id | property_name 
----+----------------+----------------+---------------
 70 |             11 |                | rx_aa
 71 |             12 |                | rx_bb
 72 |                |             11 | tx_aa
 73 |                |             12 | tx_bb
(4 rows)
```

Note also that I have used aliases for tables which generally makes queries more readable.

Read more about join types in [the documentation.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-FROM)

Answer (score 0):

It's just as easy as this:

```
select * from appliance
INNER JOIN rx_property ON rx_property.id= appliance.rx_property_id
INNER JOIN tx_property ON tx_property.id= appliance.tx_property_id
```

You can put as many joins to a single SELECT statement as you like.

Comment: I have tried this already, I am getting 0 rows returned. When executing above queries separately, I am correctly getting rows returned.

Comment: That's because you don't have records which fulfill all the requirements. So matching rx_property_id and tx_property_id in all used tables.

Comment: I think there was misunderstanding. I have updated question, please have a look.